# Issues with gnome appearance

Tags: gnome, themes, window

I just installed GNOME DE on my Ubuntu, and I have a disgusting problem, I got rounded windows with sharp corners.

[image: Here is the image]

Will be grateful for any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNOME doesn't really like the Unity theme. There are two ways to fix this. You can either switch to the default GNOME theme, or install Numix, which is sort of like a flat version of Unity.

You'll need to install the GNOME Tweak Tool first. Open a terminal and run `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`.


***Use the GNOME theme***

Search for "Tweak Tool" and open it.
Go to the Appearance tab. Change the "Window", "GTK+" and "Icons" dropdowns to "Adwaita". Relog or reboot and your theme should be GNOME's default. (No more theme issues)


***Install Numix***

Open a terminal and run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:numix/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install numix-gtk-theme numix-icon-theme-circle
```

Open Tweak Tool.
In the same fields as above, select Numix instead of Adwaita. Relog or reboot to make sure the theme applies fully.

---

Hopefully, you won't have those corner issues again.

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried first way, and it worked. I am really new to Linux,  so it is difficult for me to work with PPAs, I dont know are they safe, or are they overwriting something, should I remove them after, etc. So I did it first way.
And one question, shuld I remove gnome-tweak-tool after applying the theme ?

Comment: PPAs are repositories: pretty much indexes that show Ubuntu where to download the necessary installer packages. They don't overwrite anything, but do be careful when adding one (make sure it's a trusted source, and not some obscure URL). Numix is trusted, so you needn't worry about adding it. I would recommend that, once you add a PPA, you keep it, unless you don't have anything installed from it. The PPA is needed to receive updates to packages installed from it. You might as well keep Tweak Tool, as you'll never know when you need it again. However, there should be no harm in removing it.

Comment: That was very informative, thank you one more time.